# How to mock local function in Karma?

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

I have to test a js file that looks like the following:

```
const varA = document.A;
// some action with foo and bar
return varA;

function foo() {
}

function bar() {
}
```

I can mock `document.A` property this way:

```
sandbox.stub(document, 'A').value('test value');
```

But is there any way to mock local `foo` and `bar` functions?